# Camera preview in another view issue with width

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6

I have added camera preview on the half of the iPhone screen.

```
-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    AVCaptureSession *session = [[AVCaptureSession alloc] init];
    session.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetMedium;

    CALayer *viewLayer = self.vImagePreview.view.layer;
    NSLog(@"viewLayer = %@", viewLayer);

    AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer *captureVideoPreviewLayer = [[AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer alloc] initWithSession:session];

    captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.view.bounds;
    [self.vImagePreview.view.layer addSublayer:captureVideoPreviewLayer];

    AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];

    NSError *error = nil;
    AVCaptureDeviceInput *input = [AVCaptureDeviceInput deviceInputWithDevice:device error:&error];
    if (!input) {
        // Handle the error appropriately.
        NSLog(@"ERROR: trying to open camera: %@", error);
    }
    [session addInput:input];

    [session startRunning];
}
```

I added camera view controller in viewDidLoad method and set it's frame:

```
vImagePreview.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 179);
```

But camera view isn't 320. Any idea how to set width of the camera view add this way?
Height is fine but width is about 100 wide.
It's like on this link width is 320 but camera view is from some reason smaller (width).
![enter image description here][1]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.view.bounds;
```

This is the culprit.

You need to add `videoGravity`(Indicates how the video is displayed within a player layer’s bounds rect.) with `AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill` property
and then assign the `bounds` and the last but not the least,
you need to give the `x and y- coordinates that establishes the center of a rectangle.`

```
CGRect bounds=self.vImagePreview.view.layer.bounds;
avLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
avLayer.bounds=bounds;
avLayer.position=CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(bounds), CGRectGetMidY(bounds));
```

Comment: This works for me the first time I set it up. But after the application went into the background and I do this again it is offset.

Answer (score 0):

Change your camera preview screen width and check.

Comment: Preview screen is 320/179 as you can see form the code captureVideoPreviewLayer.frame = self.vImagePreview.view.bounds; I add this values 320/179 to the previewLayer too.